# Phonegap Phaser game not registering onTap events

Tags: cordova, phonegap, phaser-framework

I have a super basic [Phaser](http://phaser.io/) test which runs **great** in the browser but when I use Phonegap to export it to iOS, none of the input events work.

If I serve up the app using the browser export, open that on my phone through the ip address, it also doesn't register any click events.

I've done a lot of google searching but nothing has really turned up. Wondering if anyone else is having/has had trouble with this? I'm running on the latest and greatest stuff.

```
game.input.onTap.add(function(){ //I do stuff }, this);
```

[Phaser input reference](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Input.html)

I've also added the Cordova device ready event for good measure.. Didn't make any difference

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("device ready");
        //Main Game object
        game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update
        });
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sigh.. Turns out I wasn’t actually running on the newest version of Phaser. Not sure how I managed to download the wrong version but I did.

Hopefully this helps other people who also forget to check their versions.